# Server.ScriptTimeout value not Changing in ASP.Web page

Tags: asp.net

I have two report pages that require extra processing time in an asp.net 2.0 intranet website.  The website expires at 90 seconds, but my attempts to set the expiration on the report page at 1800 seconds always fails with a timeout around 90 seconds.

The report page has `<% Server.ScriptTimeout = 1800; %>` in the aspx page just under the @ Page line.  Previously, I set this value in the code on page load.  In either case, the page expires around 90 seconds.

The web.config has the executionTimeout="90" and compilation debug="false".  Changing the executionTimeout always works, but I don't want the entire site to expire at 1800 seconds, just the report page.

Also, I have experimented with the web.config setting below the main system.web setting:

```
<location path="Reports">
  <system.web>
   <httpRuntime executionTimeout="1800"/>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

The fourth attempt was to create a web.config file in the "reports" sub-folder. This also failed.

I appreciate any feedback.  (The code was typed, not copied)

Answer (score 0):

The executionTimeout property will only work when **Debug** is set to **False** in web.config.

I presume you are using asp.net forms and Why not try creating a base for all report pages override Page load and OnUnload events.

```
     //On Report Page Base class

private const int PageRequestTimeout = 1800;
private const int DefaultRequestTimeout = 110;// 110 seconds  

protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
 {
     Server.ScriptTimeout = PageRequestTimeout;
      base.OnLoad(e);
 }
 protected override void OnUnload(EventArgs e)
 {
       Server.ScriptTimeout = PageRequestTimeout;
        base.OnUnload(e);

       // reset  the page request timeout
        Server.ScriptTimeout = DefaultRequestTimeout;
 }
```

MSDN Reads as follows [MSDN Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.scripttimeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> If you set the debug attribute of the element to true in the
>   Web.config file, the value of ScriptTimeout will be ignored.